# XSLT:Break up tag structure at specic tag

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file processed using XSLT **2.0** that can contain a tag adhering to this DTD fragment

```
<!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA|foo|bar|table)* >
```

That is the input file could look like this (just one of all the possible variants)

```
<p>foobar
  <table attr1="a" attr2="b">...</table>
  <foo fooattr="FOO">fdaghd</foo><bar>something</bar>sometext
  <table attr1="B">...</table>
</p>
```

I need to convert this into (where namespace must be preserved, that is no usage of copy or copy-of as these creates `xmlns=""` attributes)

```
<p>foobar</p>
<table attr1="a" attr2="b">...</table>
<p>
  <foo fooattr="FOO">fdaghd</foo>
  <bar>something</bar>
  sometext
</p>
<table attr1="B">...</table>
```

That is "split" the `<p>`-tag whenever a `<table>`-tag is found and continue with the `<p>` after (if there are any children left).

Please note that this is also a valid input example

```
    <p><table attr1="a" attr2="b">...</table></p>
```

which should just be converted into

```
    <table attr1="a" attr2="b">...</table>
```

and that this is also a valid input example

```
    <p>bbbb<foo>aaaa</foo></p>
```

which should not be converted at all, that is output should be

```
    <p>bbbb<foo>aaaa</foo></p>
```

The XSLT I have so far includes this

```
<xsl:template match="p[table]">
  <xsl:call-template name="split-paragraph">
    <xsl:with-param name="tables" select="table"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="split-paragraph">
  <xsl:param name="tables"/>

  <xsl:if test="$tables">
    <xsl:for-each select="$tables[1]">
      <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::node//table)">
          <p><xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::node()[not(table)]"/></p>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::node()//table)">
          <p><xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node[. &lt;&lt; following-sibling::node()[not(name()='table')][1]]"/></p>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:call-template name="split-paragraph">
        <xsl:with-param name="tables"
                        select="$tables[position() > 1]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:element name="table">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element()"><xsl:copy/></xsl:template>
```

which applied to

```
<p>foo
  <table attr1="gazonk"><a>bar</a></table>
  <bar>xyzzy</bar>
  <table attr2="2"><b>fie</b></table>
  shfjkdashndk
</p>
```

generates

```
<p>foo</p>
<table attr1="gazonk">
  <a>bar</a>
</table>
<p>
</p>
<p>foo
  <table attr1="gazonk">
    <a>bar</a>
  </table>
  <bar>xyzzy</bar>
</p>
<table attr2="2">
  <b>fie</b>
</table>
<p>shfjkdashndk</p>
```

which is not the desired output. I want this

```
<p>foo</p>
<table attr1="gazonk">
  <a>bar</a>
</table>
<p><bar>xyzzy</bar></p>
<table attr2="2">
  <b>fie</b>
</table>
<p>shfjkdashndk</p>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 here?

Comment: XSLT 2.0 (and Saxon 9 HE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 1.0, you can treat this as a grouping problem. You are grouping not-table elements together, with the grouping being done on the number of table elements that precede the nodes to group. Using [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), you would define a key like so

```
<xsl:key name="group" match="p/node()[not(self::table)]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '-', count(preceding-sibling::table))" />
```

(The `generate-id()` is here to cope with multiple **p** elements in the XML)

You would then start off by having a template to match the **p** elements, where you would skip over the element, but them select its children, using a "mode" to indicate special processing (and to avoid having two templates that match the same node)

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="group" />
</xsl:template>
```

You would need a template to match the first non-table element that occurs in each group, so you could then add the **p** tag around it and the other items in the group, like so

```
<xsl:template match="node()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '-', count(preceding-sibling::table)))[1])]" mode="group">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '-', count(preceding-sibling::table)))"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

(Note, the XSLT would be using the [Identity Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to output other nodes to the output)

Matching the table is more straight-forward:

```
 <xsl:template match="table" mode="group"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Finally, you would need a template to match other nodes not picked up by the previous two templates, to ignore them (as the previous "group" template will have already outputted them. This is where the use of "mode" becomes apparent)

```
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="group" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="group" match="p/node()[not(self::table)]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '-', count(preceding-sibling::table))" />

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="group" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '-', count(preceding-sibling::table)))[1])]" mode="group">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '-', count(preceding-sibling::table)))"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="table" mode="group"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="group" /> 

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:** To cope with namespaces, in XSLT 1.0, you will have to replace all instances of `p` in xpath expressions with `*[local-name() = 'p']`, and similarly for table. You are also going to have to use **xsl:element** to create the new **p** element with the same namespace.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="group" match="*[local-name() = 'p']/node()[not(self::*[local-name() = 'table'])]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '-', count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = 'table']))" />

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'p']">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="group" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '-', count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = 'table'])))[1])]" mode="group">
        <xsl:element name="p" namespace="{namespace-uri(..)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('group', concat(generate-id(..), '-', count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = 'table'])))"/>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'table']" mode="group"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="group" /> 

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT 2.0

Here is the XSLT 2.0 solution, where you can use **xsl:for-each-group** to group elements. In this case, I am grouping adjacent elements together, depending on whether they are a table or not.

Also not the use of wildcards in checking for namespaces (which will cope whether namespaces are present or not)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*:p">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::*:table)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::*:table">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="p" namespace="{namespace-uri(..)}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works "almost" (I'm using XSLT 2.0). Alas it gives xmlns="" (due to usage of copy construct, but I guess easily fixable using explicit <xsl:element> creation?). More importantly the text nodes does not get wrapped at all. :(

**This input**  
`...</title>
<p>foo<table attr1="gazonk"><a>bar</a></table><bar>xyzzy</bar><bar>zork</bar><table attr2="2"><b>fie</b></table>shfjkdashndk</p>
<p>This...`

**gives this output**  

`</title>foo<table attr1="gazonk">
<a>bar</a>
</table>
<p>
<bar xmlns="">
</bar>
<bar xmlns="">
</bar>
</p>zork<table attr2="2">
<b>fie</b>
</table>shfjkdashndkThis`

Comment: @3721979 I've made an edit to my answer to show how to retain namespaces.

Comment: Thank you @Tim. Is it also possible to address the text-node issue with some simple edit? That is none of text nodes are within <p>-tags (and all non-table tags in sequence needs to share the same <p>-tag)...

Comment: If I remove the `namespace="{namespace-uri(..)}` from the creation of `p` tag this solution works! :) But can someone please tell me how to simplifiy the Muenchian grouping using XSLT 2.0 primitives?

Comment: I've amended my answer to show the XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: Thank you! The XSLT 2.0 solution works like a charm. :) Can you please tell me what the notation "boolean(self::*:table)" means? And how does that enable you to access the table nodes when iterating over the groups?

Comment: "boolean(self::*:table)" (or just "boolean(self::table)" in XSLT 1.0) returns true if the node being tested is a "table" element, false otherwise. So, non-table nodes evaluate to false, and the for-each-group will group all the "false" ones together. Read up on grouping at http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1314

Answer (score 0):

try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[table]/child::text()">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[table]/*[not(self::table)]">
        <p>
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[table]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works "almost". Each individual element gets wrapped in a <p></p> tag. :(

I will update the example to better show the wanted result.